# append and closest for each div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put an image inside the closest div searched by class using closest but it just won't append.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/13029/

```
$(".fac").each(function() {
  $(this).closest(".bac").append($(this));
});
```

Comment: `fac` is not a *child* of `bac`, so `$(".fac").closest(".bac")` won't ever give a result.   It's always handy to have a quick read of the documentation for a method as the names aren't always what you might expect:  https://api.jquery.com/closest/   (closest parent, not closest sibling).

Comment: And if jsfiddle is down?  There's a reason code should be in the question.  Please also read [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `closest()`, it's `prev()` actually. So do like below:-

```
$(".fac").each(function() {
  $(this).prev(".bac").append($(this));
});
```

You can use :-

```
$(".fac").each(function() {
  $(this).prev().find(".bac").append($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest` doesn't look for siblings. So you should either use `prev` or use a wrapper for image and div so that you can use `closest` to find closest wrapper and then find the div inside it.

Also you should use `appendTo` to append the element at the end of the div.

```js
   $("img.fac").each(function() {
                   $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('div.bac'));
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="fli_234" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a title=" SPORT LINAV HUD"
                                                       href="xom/aine-sunroof-nav-hud-234.html"><img
        alt="BmwPORT LINE SUNROOF NAV HUD"
        src="http://xm/templatesank_10x7.gif"
        data-1x="http://xm/files/11-2016/ad234/863_sold_en.jpg"
        data-2x="http:/xm/files/11-2016245661706047863_sold_en.jpg"
        style="background-image: url(http://wwom/files/11-2016/ad234/15021245661706047863_sold_en.jpg);"
        width="209" height="126"></a>
    <ul class="ad-info">
        <li class="title" title=""><a
                href="xxxx.html">
            3 SeNAV HUD</a></li>
        <li class="services" style="height:20px;"></li>
        <li class="fields"><span id="flf_234_Category_ID">Cars</span><span id="flf_234_condition_tool">Used</span><span
                id="flf_234_carroceria">Sedan</span><span id="flf_234_year_of_production">2013</span><span
                id="flf_234_mileage">28112 km</span></li>
        <li class="two-inline price_tag">
            <nav id="fav_234" class="favorite add" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="icon"></span></nav>
            <div><span class="converted-price">158,413 Lei</span><span class="hide">34,500 €</span></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
        <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="bac"></div>
<img class="fac" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="height:45px;">       
        </div>
```